# Javascript submit doest work or Php doest work

Tags: javascript, php

hi i have a form and the forms end with .html but i am running them on xampp on the local server. my form does not post anyhow button type I did not submit button because i made a control with javascript what is the solution

```
 <td><form name="kayit" id="kayit_form" method="POST" action="learn.html"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="kullanici_adi">Kullanıcı Adı</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="kullanici_ad_kayit" id="kullanici_adi"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="password">Şifre</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="kullanici_sifre_kayit" id="password" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="confirm_pasword">Şifre Tekrarı</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="password" name="kullanici_sifre_kayit_tekrar" id="confirm_password" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label for="email_kayit">E-mail</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="email" name="kullanici_email_kayit" id="email_kayit" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="button" onclick="onayla()"   value="KAYIT OL!"></td>
```

This is php code in html file

```
         <?php
include('db.php');
if (!isset($_POST['kayit']))
{
    echo 'test';
}
else
{
 echo "test1";
}
?>
```

and this is too javascript code

```
function onayla(){
    var a = document.getElementById('kullanici_adi').value;
    var x = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
    var e = document.getElementById('email_kayit').value;
    if(x.length == 0 || y.length==0 || e.length==0 || a.length==0){
        window.alert("Lütfen Boş Bırakmayın");

    }
    else if(x != y){
      window.alert('Şifreler Eşit Değil Tekrar Kontrol Edin');

    }
    else{

        document.getElementById('kayit_form').submit();
    }

}
```

Comment: is the onayla() function being called? try alert('here') in the function and see if its gets executed

Comment: "_This is php code in html file_" PHP doesn't get parsed/executed in `.html` files (unless you told your webserver to do so). Rename your `learn.html` to `learn.php`, and change your form action accordingly

Comment: Calling function is okay, but the form is not submitted

Comment: As @kerbholz said, first change the file extension to `.php`.

Comment: I changed but doest work again

Comment: I think there is no form via javascript

Comment: Is this complete code because it doesn't seem to have a closing form tag </form>. Add this and see.

Comment: yes, i wrote short code

Comment: by the way I fixed the problem but I dont know how to fix

Comment: the extension of the page worked html and post again